# Build Go bindings for multiple library versions?

Tags: go, preprocessor, gtk3, gtk2

I've encountered a small [hiccup](https://github.com/mattn/go-gtk/issues/225) when trying to merge the GTK3 support in the [go-gtk fork](https://github.com/agl/go-gtk) used by [pond](https://github.com/agl/pond) with the upstream [go-gtk](https://github.com/mattn/go-gtk) based on GTK2.

These `cgo pkg-config` lines that specify the GTK version must afaik appear in every file, which prevents bindings common to both GTK 2 and 3 from existing in a common file.

I suppose the "idiomatic" hack to build compile a file against multiple  GTK versions is : Place the common code in a `foo_common.go` file, so that it never builds.  Use a `perl` or `bash + sed` script to build `foo2.go` and `foo3.go` from `foo_common.go` by fixing the `cgo pkg-config` lines and adding go build directives for a gtk2 tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [build constrain](http://golang.org/pkg/go/build/) aka tags to achieve that.

First you have to split the files that use gtk2 and gtk3, then assuming you want gtk3 to be the default (I'll frown if you make gtk2 the default):

gtk3.go:

```
// +build !gtk2

package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("gtk3")
}
```

gtk2.go:

```
// +build gtk2

package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("gtk2")
}
```

Then to test it:

```
$ go build; and ./constrains
gtk3
$ go build -tags gtk2; and ./constrains
gtk2
```

Comment: No.  Build tags do not suffice because the `cgo pkg-config` lines must appear in *every* file.  You can use build tags together with a preprocessor like cpp or perl, like I described in the question.

Comment: Yes, I'd agree about gtk3 being the default of course, not sure why anyone even bothers building support for gtk2 at this point, maybe it's a smaller footprint or something.